# Django AllAuth How do you Customize your own HTML or CSS

Tags: django, django-allauth

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load url from future %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Signup" %}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

</style>
<h1><b>Free Membership</b>Sign up Today</h1>
<h1>{% trans "Sign Up" %}</h1>

<p>{% blocktrans %}Already have an account? Then please <a href="{{ login_url }}">sign in</a>.{% endblocktrans %}</p>

<form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'account_signup' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  {% if redirect_field_value %}
  <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
  {% endif %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Sign Up" %} &raquo;</button>
</form>

<h1><b>Free Membership</b>Sign up Today</h1>
{% endblock %}
{% block content2 %}
{% endblock %}
```

This is the original Code from Django All Auth.

What I want to do is bring it more to life like add some better HTML5 or CSS to it when I do it does not change?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Templates in Allauth registration for Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551167/templates-in-allauth-registration-for-django)

Answer (score 13):

Here's my login.html template (I'm using Bootstrap, Jquery and Font-Awesome for the icons).

```html
{% extends "account/base.html" %} {% load i18n custom_tags account %} {% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %} {% block common_scripts %}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Load jquery straight from the cdn for this page.
  $(function() {
    // We need some mappings for Providers names from AllAuth to the icon class names.
    $('.btn-google').addClass('btn-google-plus');
    $('.btn-linkedin_oauth2').addClass('btn-linkedin');
    $('.fa-linkedin_oauth2').addClass('fa-linkedin');
    $('#id_login').addClass('form-control').removeAttr('autofocus').blur();
    $('#id_password').addClass('form-control');
  });
</script>
{% endblock %} {% block content %}
<div class="container col-md-12">
  <div class="well login-well">
    <div class="socialaccount_ballot">
      <ul class="socialaccount_providers">
        {% load socialaccount %} {% for provider in socialaccount.providers %} {% if provider.id == "openid" %} {% for brand in provider.get_brands %}
        <li>
          <a title="{{ brand.name }}" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-md btn-{{ provider.id }} socialaccount_provider {{ brand.id }}" href="{% provider_login_url provider.id openid=brand.openid_url process=" login " %}">
            <i class="fa fa-{{ provider.id }}"></i>Log in with {{ brand.name }}
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %} {% endif %}
        <li>
          <a title="{{ provider.name }}" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-md socialaccount_provider btn-{{ provider.id }}" href="{% provider_login_url provider.id process=" login " %}">
            <i class="fa fa-{{ provider.id }}"></i>Log in with {{ provider.name }}
          </a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      <hr>

      <form class="django-login" method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
        {% csrf_token %} {% if form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
          <ul class="alert-message">
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="input-group {% if form.login.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
          <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>
          {{ form.login }}
        </div>

        <div class="input-group {% if form.password.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
          <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span>
          {{ form.password }}
        </div>

        <div class="fieldWrapper form-inline remember text-center">
          {{ form.remember }}
          <label for="id_remember" class="text-muted">Remember me</label>
        </div>

        {% if redirect_field_value %}
        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />{% endif %}
        <div class="btn-div pull-center">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">{% trans "Sign In" %}</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <small><a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'account_reset_password' %}">{% trans "Forgot Password?" %}</a></small>
      <br>
      <small><a class="text-muted" href="{% url 'signup' %}">Sign up</a></small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

And how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Do you have eventueally css for socialaccount_ballot and socialaccount_providers things? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can put custom templates for allauth in your `template` directory under `account` folder. Django allauth would take the custom template from it and renders it.

Following is sample signup page I have created some days ago:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load socialaccount %}

{% block extra_body %}account-bg{% endblock %}

{% block partial %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="account-form-container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3>Create New Account</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <form class="form-horizontal signup-form" id="userSignupForm" action="{% url "account_signup" %}" method="post" role="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {% if request.GET.next %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{request.GET.next}}">
                    {% endif %}

                    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
                    <div class="fieldWrapper alert alert-danger">
                        <ul>
                        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                                <li>{{ error | lower}}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon {% if form.email.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                                <i class="icon-user"></i>
                                <input class="form-control login-field" type="text" id="id_email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                                <span class="help-block">{{ form.email.errors }}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon {% if form.password1.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                                <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                                <input class="form-control login-field" type="password" id="id_password1" name="password1" placeholder="Password">
                                <span class="help-block">{{ form.password1.errors }}</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group inner-addon left-addon {% if form.password1.errors %}has-error{% endif %}">
                                <i class="icon-lock"></i>
                                <input class="form-control login-field" type="password" id="id_password2" name="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                <span class="help-block">{{ form.password1.errors }}</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <div class="col-md-5">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-complete btn-bold pull-right">Sign Up</button>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: I actually used your code and it looks the same strange

Comment: @RobertDjangostudent Make sure its picking overridden template. Also  You'll need to create/change base.html also. You can add your own styling in it.

Comment: great I have my own base.html already but for some reason I think its getting the base.html from the django allauth , templates/auth/base.html I want it to get the base.html from my static how would i get that to happen

Comment: Ohh I see...did you check example project in allauth? https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/tree/master/example

Comment: May be something changed, what's your django version?

Comment: Im using django1.7 the django allauth i use in the template is coming from the auth folder then in the template i am using {% extends "auth/base.html" %}